# Upload a file using WebDriver & PyWinAuto

Tags: python, selenium, pywinauto

I have a python script that tries to upload a file from my PC to a web application.
I press via WebDriver the specific upload button in the browser and then a Win7 explorer window opens for me to navigate and select the desired file to upload.
How could I manipulate this window with pywinauto?

optional: could this be done in linux as well (with an appropriate library I suppose) ?

This is my sample code:

```
wd.find_element_by_css_selector("img.editLecturesButtons.fromVideo").click()
#switch to the lightbox
wd.switch_to_frame(int("1"))
#hit upload
wd.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='fileUpload']").click()
#TODO
import os,pywinauto.application
file = os.path.normpath("C:\Users\me\Desktop\image.jpg")
....
```

Comment: Most Webdriver users find changing the order to "send filepath to input element" THEN "click upload/submit button". Have you tried this? It can make things easier as it is difficult to interact with the file-upload managers.

Comment: I have read about this solution but I think that it does not apply to me. Inside the web application I press a button and a lightbox appears  .The application uses the Filepicker API to upload and convert files.  The html I found for the specific button is the following:

Comment: <div id="fileInputContainer">
<a id="fileUploadDummy" class="btn">Choose File</a>
<input id="fileUploadInput" type="file" multiple="multiple" accept="application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation,video/3gpp,video/x-msvideo,video/x-flv,video/mp4,video/x-matroska,video/quicktime,video/mp4,video/mpeg,video/mpeg,video/ogg,video/webm,video/x-ms-wmv,application/zip" name="fileUpload">
</div>

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mark, you should try the Webdriver methods. Regard to pywinauto, code may looks like:

```
import pywinauto

pwa_app = pywinauto.application.Application()
w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'Open', class_name='#32770')[0]
window = pwa_app.window_(handle=w_handle)
ctrl = window['Name']
ctrl.SetText(file)
ctrl = window['OK']
ctrl.Click()
```

This sollution only for Windows, since pywinauto uses win32 api.

Comment: I will try the pywinauto approach, although the production code will run on Ubuntu.